# Is there a way to access the position of a vueuse UseDraggable renderless component in the script block?

Tags: vue.js, vueuse

I have a component that used Vueuse's UseDraggable renderless component. I use the renderless component because I can then use the storage-key and storage-type properties out-of-the-box.

This works fine, but people can drag the window outside the viewport. When releasing the drag there is no way to reset it. That is why I would like to reset the position if the component manually. I then first need to know if the user left the component outside of the viewport and to do that I need to be able to access the position.

Is there a way to access the position of the component from within the script block instead of just in the slot

```
  <template>
    <UseDraggable
      v-slot="{ position }"
      class="fixed z-10"
      :initial-value="{ x: 0, y: 0 }"
      storage-key="vueuse-draggable"
      storage-type="session"
    >
      <p>I can acces position here {{ position }}</p>
    </UseDraggable>
  </template>

  <script lang="ts" setup>
  import { UseDraggable } from "@vueuse/components";

  // But I want to access the position here
  </script>
```

Comment: In case of vueuse it's always reduced to checking source code. As you can see, the comp doesn't expose any internal data https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/main/packages/core/useDraggable/component.ts . The answer is no. You can copy and customize it if you need

Comment: Thanks, it’s indeed best to simply check the source.